# Unable to create project Prism.Maui Visual Studio 2022

Tags: prism, visual-studio-2022

Steps I'm following:

1. Open Visual Studio 2022 with no project
2. Install Prism.Templates::8.1.97 (dotnet new install Prism.Templates::8.1.97)
3. File > New > Project > Prism .NET App (Dan Siegel)
4. Select project name and location. Press Create.

Visual Studio gets stuck for a few minutes creating the project and then, finally crashes, leaving a unusable project.

### Extra info:

| Success: Prism.Templates::8.1.97 installed the following templates: |
| --- |

| Template Name |
| --- |
| Prism .NET MAUI App |
| MAUI/Android/iOS/macOS/Mac |
| Prism Blank App (Uno Platform) |
| Platform/WebAssembly/iOS/Android/WinUI/UWP |
| Prism Blank App (WPF) |
| Prism Blank App (Xamarin.Forms) |
| Prism Full App (WPF) |
| Prism Module (WPF) |
| Prism Module (Xamarin) |

| dotnet workload list |
| --- |

| Installed Workload Id | Manifest Version | Installation Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| maui | 8.0.6/8.0.100 | SDK 8.0.200 |
| maui-windows | 8.0.6/8.0.100 | VS 17.9.34622.214 |
| android | 34.0.79/8.0.100 | VS 17.9.34622.214 |
| maccatalyst | 17.2.8022/8.0.100 | VS 17.9.34622.214 |
| ios | 17.2.8022/8.0.100 | VS 17.9.34622.214 |